# puppet stage syntax error

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I have a shell script to install nodejs module packages which should be execute after all packages are installed.
I defined a stage 'last' after the Stage[main]
here is my code

```
stage { 'last': }
Stage[main] -> Stage[last]
class npm {
        stage => last,
        file { '/tmp/nodejs.sh':
                 source => 'puppet:///modules/npm/nodejs.sh',
                 ensure => present,                
        }
        exec { 'install web development nodejs packages':
               command => '/tmp/nodejs.sh',
               user => "root",
               require => Package['nodejs', 'npm']
        }
}
```

However, it return an error

> ==> default: Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '=>'; expected '}' at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-/manifests/init.pp:90 on node local.d
>       ev

the line 90 is pointed at "stage => last,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts that sadly share very similar syntax.

#### Class definition

```
class <name> {
    # includes of other classes ...
    # resource declarations ...
}
```

#### Class declaration

```
# usually
include <name>
# ...but if you need stages
class {
    '<name>':
        stage => 'last'
}
```

The latter is known as resource-like class declaration (and it has some [caveats](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like)).

Also note that stages are somewhat frowned upon in the community.

If you don't use virtual package resources, you can avoid the use of stages.

```
Package<| |> -> Exec['install web development nodejs packages']
```

This establishes a `before` relation from all `package` resources to your `exec`.